# What is the best current practise to insert default/initial data into a ruby on rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I have a new rails app with a fresh database and I want to add some default entries, like admin with default password etc.

How should I proceed?

I know of two possibilities, that both have drawbacks:

- Use ruby code in migration: User.create!(:email => "admin@example.com", :password => "abc")
- Use SQL code in migration: INSERT INTO users (id, email, password) VALUES (1, 'admin@example.com', 'abc')

The first alternative can break if I alter my code in later versions. The second is somewhat DBMS dependent.

As I do not plan to change my database, I would go with SQL code, but are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd use seed data

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

One advantage of this is that rake db:setup calls rake db:seed after it has created the database.  Which is perfect for new machines.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Ruby code in `db/seeds.rb`.

The comment at the start of that file says:

> This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the
>   database with its default values.  The data can then be loaded with
>   the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).

This is preferred over putting initialization code in the migration files.

Answer (score 0):

I use the seed_fu gem, I haven't run into anything yet that it couldn't handle for me:

https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu